# What are the limitations of CCGs?

Tags: syntax, generative-grammar

I've read that context free grammar (CFG) has a wide variety of natural language phenomena that it can't model, such as ellipsis

> I gave Tom a cake, and John an hamburger

And that combinatory categorial grammar (CCG), can handle them with type-raising.

What are the natural language phenomena that CCG is having trouble parsing?

Comment: I don't know what "model" means here.  Why do you think your example sentence is a problem for CFG?

Comment: The ellipsis phenomenon cannot be parsed using only BNF derivation rules formalism

Comment: I have news for you.  It can, using the slash categories invented by Gerald Gazdar.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_phrase_structure_grammar